# Dreamfactory - MVC PartialView Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got to open a pop-up which will display the list of `Customers`. I'm Using DreamFactory for all CRUD operations. But DreamFactory has got all operation as `async` operation and while loading partial view it gives error:

> HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous operation to complete.

I'm using below code to load the partial view -

```
@Html.Action("GetAddressListForPartial", "Customer", new { CustomerID = Model.CustomerID })
```

This is my controller method

```
public async Task ActionResult CustomerList()
{
     Models.Customers oCustomers = await new DataAccessLayer.DataAccess().GetCustomerList(databaseApi);
     return View("CustomerList", oCustomers);
}
```

Please let me know if there any workaround to handle this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is not just related to DreamFactory. With ASP.Net MVC 5 and earlier, child actions can't be  executed when your action method use `async`. 
Child action must run synchronously. If you want your code to work you must remove `async` keywork hence removing `Task`. At the end you must have this :

```
public ActionResult CustomerList()
{
     Models.Customers oCustomers = new DataAccessLayer.DataAccess().GetCustomerList(databaseApi).Result;
     return View("CustomerList", oCustomers);
}
```

With ASP.Net MVC 6, `ViewComponent` will allow child action to be executed asynchronously.

Comment: Yes i found this solution in other post as well, But issue is i can't use MVC6 6 and my client want me to use DreamFactory. DreamFactory provides asych operations only. Do we have any workaround to tackle this situation?

Comment: In my answer I force your DreamFactory method to be executed synchronously by using Task.Run which will not block the main thread. With ASP.Net MVC 5 you can only do that. Explain it clearly and simply to your client and he will accept that or move to ASP.Net MVC 6 :).

Comment: If i use the solution given by you then it throws another error: Argument 1 cannot convert from System.Threading.Tasks.Task to syste.action

Comment: I edited my post to execute the task synchronously in a simpliest way.